# VBA Macro got me stumped

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a macro to make a copy of the active sheet, and rename it to whatever the value of cell 'C2' is. The only problem is, that when it copies the sheet, it somehow removes the form buttons from the top of my worksheet and replaces them with the code =$c$2 in cell 'AF'.

As far as i can see from the VBA code there is nothing that refers to the cell 'AF'. Can anyone tell me why it's doing this ?

```
Sub Copy_Rename()
    Dim shtName As String
    shtName = ActiveSheet.Name
    ActiveSheet.Copy before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = Range("C2").Value
    Sheets(shtName).Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Copy_Rename()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True '<< to also copy objects not just cell contents etc
    sht.Copy before:=sht
    'Get the just-created sheet
    With Sheets(sht.Index - 1)
        .Name = sht.Range("C2").Value
        .Activate
    End With
End Sub
```